# setting connection parameters in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know if it's possible to set a connection in a web config of my web project that depends of a dll and not from the connection String.

**UPDATE**

Ok I have a dll, that make's a connection with my database, i want to know if it's possible to configure my web.config to get the connection from the dll and not from the string connection.

Comment: not following, please re-word.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm finding your question a little difficult to understand. Could you possibly rephrase it a bit? Cheers. :)

Comment: I already modifed the question

Comment: Why does your web.config need to connect to something with a connection string? The web.config can **store** a connection string centrally, but it never actually uses it itself. Therefore your problem isn't that your web.config needs to use a different connection string, it's that the connection you're creating needs to look at the DLL string instead of the web.config string.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. web.config contains a connection string. It doesn't "get" a connection string (or do anything else - it just contains stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you edit the web.config in your code to set the connection based on your dependency at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in fact it's the proper way to do it.  You simply have teh DLL read the application's Web.config:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];
```

Where MyConnectionString is:

```
`<connectionStrings>
   <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="<your connection string>" providerName="<provider name>" />
 </connectionStrings>`
```

**EDIT TO ADD**

I answered before the edit to your question.  However, I still question your approach.  The whole purpose of a DLL (in my experience) is to encapsulate code that can be used by multiple applications.  The application calling the DLL should be responsible for setting the connection string.

However, if there's some reason that you must have the connection string in the DLL (hardcoded, I assume?), you would need to expose it (like via a property) so that consumers of the DLL would have access to it.  In that event, the application could use the property to get the connection string.

Stephen Kinningham's answer is probably the route to go for what you appear to be attempting, but honestly, I can't think of a reason off the top of my head why you would want to.

Comment: I think he wants the assembly to be the provider of the connection string, not a consumer of it, i.e. the inverse of the normal way shown in your answer.

Comment: @hatchet - yeah, I saw his edit after I posted my answer.  I added an explanation as to why I thought this wasn't the best way to go, but there's always the possibility there's some reason he has to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>    

<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=MYDBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID_OR_ADMIN;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

 </connectionStrings>
```